# Synchronized interactivity between two R plots (plotly and leaflet)

Tags: r, leaflet, plotly, synchronized

I’d like to synchronize the interactivity of two R plots: a plotly plot and a leaflet map. The plotly plot graphs a time series for a specific location in the leaflet map. In other words, I’d like to select a location (or group of locations) in a map and see the corresponding selection in the ploty plot and vice versa select a time series in the plotly plot and see the corresponding marker in the map highlighted. So, in both directions.

The attached file (dataset1) is a R list that contains all data. Each element of the list is a dataset (time series) for each location. The linked variable for both plots is “Codi.Estació”.

I’ve tried the crosstalk package but the authors warn that “Crosstalk currently only works for linked brushing and filtering of views that show individual data points, not aggregate or summary views”.  I’m not interested in an individual data point but a whole time series.

Could anyone help me how to handle that?  Tips, examples, other packages (instead of leaflet) are welcome?

Thank you very much and have a nice summer,

Download the dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PkPm1ObcEer8Lne5vJMZR6MdFTONRSvY/view?usp=sharing

Download HTML output: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YHko4V-iAUZqZr3wNC7zGEdrMhjmykSA

The code in R Markdown (*.Rmd) (to run in Rstudio):

````
---
title: "Piezometers La Bisbal del Penedès "
author: "J.M. Campanera"
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
social: menu
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(flexdashboard)
load("dataset1.RData")
```

Column {data-width=700}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Water depth
```{r echo=FALSE}
# Plot 1
p<-plot_ly()
for (i in 1:length(dataset1)) {
p<-add_trace(p,name=dataset1[[i]]$Codi.Estació[1],x=dataset1[[i]]$Data,y=dataset1[[i]]$Valor,mode = 'scatter',type="scatter")
}
p
```

Column {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### well locations
```{r echo=FALSE}
m <- leaflet()
m<-addTiles(m)
for (i in 1:length(dataset1)) {
m<-addCircleMarkers(m,lng=dataset1[[i]]$Longitud[1], lat=dataset1[[i]]$Latitud[1],label=dataset1[[i]]$Codi.Estació[1],labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, textOnly = TRUE),popup=as.character(dataset1[[i]]$Fondària.Pou..m.[1]))
} 
m
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Finally I develop a solution:
1) Interactivity in Plotly plot and highlighting in the leaflet map: 
I used the funtion "event_data(event=c("plotly_click"))" and I get the inspiration from 
https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/

2) Interactivity in Leaflet map and highlighting in the plotly plot: 
I used the funtion "input$map_marker_click" and I get the inspiration from here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Thank you,